# How can I write the code of Bessel function with 10 term in swift?

Tags: swift, math

I hope you guys can check. when I use 5 as x it should be showing me -0.17749282815107623 but it returns -0.2792375. I couldn't where I have been doing the mistake.

```
var evenNumbers = [Int]()
for i in 2...10 {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        evenNumbers.append(i)
    }
}
func power(val: Float, power: Int)->Float{
    var c:Float = 1
    for  i in 1...power {
        c *= val
    }
    return c
}
func bessel(x: Float)->Float{
    var j0:Float = 0
    var counter = 1
    var lastDetermVal:Float = 1
    for eNumber in evenNumbers {
        print(lastDetermVal)
        if counter == 1 {
            lastDetermVal *= power(val: Float(eNumber), power: 2)
            j0 += (power(val: x, power: eNumber))/lastDetermVal
              counter = -1
        }else if counter == -1{
              lastDetermVal *= power(val: Float(eNumber), power: 2)
              j0 -= (power(val: x, power: eNumber))/lastDetermVal
              counter = 1

        }

    }

    return 1-j0
}

bessel(x: 5)
```

Function 1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake seems to be that you didn't have enough even numbers.

```
var evenNumbers = [Int]()
for i in 2...10 {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        evenNumbers.append(i)
    }
}
```

After the above is run, `evenNumbers` will be populated with `[2,4,6,8,10]`. But to evaluate 10 terms, you need even numbers up to 18 or 20, depending on whether you count `1` as a "term". Therefore, you should loop up to `18` or `20`:

```
var evenNumbers = [Int]()
for i in 2...18 { // I think the 1 at the beginning should count as a "term"
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        evenNumbers.append(i)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create this array like this:

```
let evenNumbers = (1..<10).map { $0 * 2 }
```

This means "for each number between 1 (inclusive) and 10 (exclusive), multiply each by 2".

Now your solution will give you an answer of `-0.1776034`.

---

Here's my (rather slow) solution:

```
func productOfFirstNEvenNumbers(_ n: Int) -> Float {
    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    let firstNEvenNumbers = (1...n).map { Float($0) * 2.0 }
    // ".reduce(1.0, *)" means "multiply everything"
    return firstNEvenNumbers.reduce(1.0, *)
}

func nthTerm(_ n: Int, x: Float) -> Float {
    let numerator = pow(x, Float(n) * 2)
    // yes, this does recalculate the product of even numbers every time...
    let product = productOfFirstNEvenNumbers(n)
    let denominator = product * product
    return numerator / (denominator) * pow(-1, Float(n))
}

func bessel10Terms(x: Float) -> Float {
    // for each number n in the range 0..<10, get the nth term, add them together
    (0..<10).map { nthTerm($0, x: x) }.reduce(0, +)
}

print(bessel10Terms(x: 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is a bit unreadable, however, I have written a simple solution so try to compare your intermediate results:

```
var terms: [Float] = []
let x: Float = 5

for index in 0 ..< 10 {
    guard index > 0 else {
        terms.append(1)
        continue
    }

    // calculate only the multiplier for the previous term
    // - (minus) to change the sign
    // x * x to multiply nominator
    // (Float(index * 2) * Float(index * 2) to multiply denominator
    let termFactor = -(x * x) / (Float(index * 2) * Float(index * 2))
    terms.append(terms[index - 1] * termFactor)
}

print(terms)

// sum the terms
let result = terms.reduce(0, +)
print(result)
```

One of the errors I see is the fact that you are actually calculating only 5 terms, not 10 (you iterate 1 to 10, but only even numbers).